# When I add a new column in my private folder, its effect not come to database

Tags: odoo

I installed the openerp from this link:[www.theopensourcerer.com/tag/openerp](http://www.theopensourcerer.com/tag/openerp/)

when I add a new column in my private modules, and add this column to xml then, 
its give me error, xml arch problem

Problem generated because when i add new column it not updated in tabble of object

Hope I able to explain

Comment: Can you give the full text of the error?

... Also the code of the model and views that you have extended.

Answer (score 0):

If you change:

- One **code file** (.py) you must RESTART THE SERVER. If your change implies a model schema modification (like add or modify a **column**, **sql_constraint**, etc..) you must ALSO upgrade your module.
- A **view**, **workflow**, **data** or **report** definition (.xml) you should upgrade your module.

In order to restart the openerp-service:

- If you have openerp installed like a **linux service**:

  `/etc/init.d/openerp-server restart`
- If you have openerp installed like a **ubuntu service**:

  `sudo service openerp-server restart`
- If you have openerp installed like a **windows service**:

  `net stop openerp-server && net start openerp-server`

In order to **upgrade a module**:

- Log in to **OpenERP** as **Administrator**
- Go to `Settings -> Modules -> Installed Modules`
- Select your module on the Module List
- Press the **UPGRADE** button.

if your module is not in the list (OpenERP <7.0):

- Go to `Settings -> Modules -> Upgrade Module List`

if Upgrade Module List option is not visible:

- Go to **Settings** -> **Users**
- Select **Administrator**
- Press the **EDIT** button
- Go to **Access Right**
- Check the **Technical Features** option
- Refresh the browser (F5 or CTRL+R)
- The option `Settings -> Modules -> Upgrade Module List` should be available now

Comment: i followed all your steps, but still not able to do this :(

Comment: I am using ubuntu system, before two days it was working but not now:(

Answer (score 0):

First kill all your process of openerp.

try this command: ps aux|grep openerp

It will list openerp process , use command: sudo kill -9 process id

Second use thin command on terminal: sudo su - openerp -s /bin/bash

Third use this command to update: python /opt/openerp/server/openerp-server -c /etc/openerp-server.conf -u all -d (database name)

Thanks

Comment: hi user2279598, its work for me, many many thanks, you look like angel for me